# Does the File delete() method write on the storage drive itself? (Java)

Tags: java, file, delete-file

When you right click a file and click delete, it doesn't actually erase the data. It simply just removes the reference to the file within the Master File Table.

I was wondering what the `delete()` method in the Java class, `File` does. Does it remove the reference to the file, allowing the OS to overwrite the data, or does it completely erase the file by writing 0s over it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd go with: Java calls the method that the current OS uses to normally delete a file.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the File System you are using and the OS you are using. The JVM will just pass the delete call through to an OS call.

Comment: You would have to check the JDK source to be sure, but almost certainly all it is doing is invoking the underlying OS "unlink" or "delete" system API call.

Comment: Damn it, why is there so many users that try-and-delete answers instead of improving them? Sure enough, I understand that many downvoters doesn't pay attention afterwards... but still. I think downvoters should at least say something and revise the vote after it is edited. It happened to me recently. Downvote and here we go, don't care.